# Why is the bootstrap not getting added to my website?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    
     {% if title %}
        <title>Lorem, ipsum. - {{ title }}</title>
     {% else %}
        <title>Lorem, ipsum.</title>
      {% endif %}
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class=".bg-warning">
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">How it works</a>
                <a href="#">Why us</a>
                <a href="#">Our charges</a>
                <a href="#">Account</a>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <!--ALL -->
    <!-- THE -->
    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- STARTS HERE -->
    <style>
    /* 
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        background: yellow;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        border-bottom: none;
        padding: 20px;
    } */
    
    
    </style>
    <!-- ALL -->
    <!-- THE -->
    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- ENDS HERE -->
    
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

But Bootstrap is not getting added to my website, what should I do?

Also, I tried to add some bootstrap classes but even they are not working?

I also tried to add Javascript on the bootstrap website, but even that didn't work as I wanted my website layout to be responsive.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="bg-warning">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">How it works</a>
            <a href="#">Why us</a>
            <a href="#">Our charges</a>
            <a href="#">Account</a>
            <a href="#">About us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i just realized that, it was not working before that's why